# complex series expansion for $f(z)=\frac{1}{z-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

Expand the function  $f(z)=\frac{1}{z-1}$ as as a series around $z_{0}$ in two regions

a) $$|z-z_{0}| < |1-z_{0}|$$
b) $$|z-z_{0}| > |1-z_{0}|$$ and find coefficient $a_{n}$ is each case.

I found radius of convergence to be $|1-z_{0}|$ , so for  $|z-z_{0}| < |1-z_{0}|$ I found $$f(z)= -\sum \frac{(z-z_{0})^n}{(1-z_{0})^{n+1}}$$
But what happens for case b)  $|z-z_{0}| > |1-z_{0}|$, doesn't it diverge? Can we still find series expansion for it? Will that be a Laurent or Taylor?

Comment: Yes, is a Laurent expansion

Comment: will it diverge for case b or it can be expanded?

Comment: No, f is meromorphic and then converges for all z\neq1

Comment: Can you please help me finding that expansion, I am a little confused on how to do that expansion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two cases are very similar. In case (a), you write
$${1\over z-1}={1\over (z-z_0)-(1-z_0)}={-1\over 1-z_0}\cdot {1\over 1-{z-z_0\over 1-z_0}}$$
and expand the last factor as a geometric series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty w^n$ with $w={z-z_0\over 1-z_0}$. Note that $|w|<1$ in case (a).

In case (b), you need to pull out the larger term $z-z_0$ instead, obtaining
$${1\over z-1}={1\over (z-z_0)-(1-z_0)}={1\over z-z_0}\cdot {1\over 1-{1-z_0 \over z-z_0}}$$ 
Similarly as above, let $w={1-z_0\over z-z_0}$, and observe that $|w|<1$ in case (b), so we can use the same trick again. Since $z-z_0$ now appears in the denominator of $w$, the Taylor series in $w$ will give rise to a Laurent series in $z-z_0$.